# SQL to list Employee Name and Salary one below the other

Tags: sql, oracle, select

A simple select statement on `EMPLOYEES` table gets this result.

```
select FIRST_NAME, SALARY from employees;

FIRST_NAME     SALARY
------------ --------
Steven          24000
Neena           17000
Lex             17000
```

But I need the output in this form.

```
COLUMN_TEXT
------------
Steven
24000
Neena
17000
Lex
17000
```

The employees `FIRST_NAME` needs to be in the first row followed by his/her `SALARY` in the next row.

I have tried the below. But is there a better way to do it?

```
select COLUMN_TEXT from (
select FIRST_NAME as COLUMN_TEXT
       , Row_Number() Over (Order By employee_ID) rn from employees
union all
select to_char(SALARY) as COLUMN_TEXT
      , Row_Number() Over (Order By employee_ID) rn from employees
order by rn
);
```

Comment: I'd do it in the presentation layer.

Comment: Your method is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it as you did. You could also use `unpivot`:

```
select column_text 
  from (select employee_id, first_name, to_char(salary) salary from employees) 
  unpivot (column_text for type in (first_name, salary))
  order by employee_id, type
```

**<sup>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/1423)</sup>**

`unpivot` requires Oracle 11g or later.

Comment: Somehow this feels like a better approach than mine.

Answer (score 2):

1. CHR(10) => LF, line feed

try like below

```
select FIRST_NAME || chr(10) SALARY  from employees
```